# Specific regular expressions for this formula in python

Tags: python, regex, amazon-s3

I am trying to create a regexp to match this file in my s3 bucket. This is for a S3 key that I'm trying to create, and it is obviously not being found correctly right now. Below I have provided a snapshot of the bucket the path/folder that I'm trying to access with this regexp equation.

Once again this is for a s3 key, below I will also post the portion of the code I'm using. What I'm referencing to is inside of the `try` statement.

```
class process_raw_snowplow_event_data(luigi.Task):
    dataset_date = luigi.DateParameter(default=date.today() - timedelta(days=1))
    # force_run = luigi.BoolParameter()
    _start = luigi.DateSecondParameter(default=datetime.utcnow())
    file_root = luigi.Parameter()


def download_s3_file(self, s3_filename):

    local_filename = "/Users/xxx/etl/%s" % s3_filename

    s3_file_full_path =re.compile("snowplow-enrich-output/enriched/archive/run=" + self.dataset_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") +r"-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}/*.")


    try:
        s3.download_file(Bucket=os.environ.get('SP_BUCKET'), Key=s3_file_full_path, Filename=local_filename)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("%s - Could not retrieve %s because: %s" % ("download_s3_file()", s3_filename, e))
        raise
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 199, in run
new_deps = self._run_get_new_deps()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 139, in _run_get_new_deps
task_gen = self.task.run()
  File "target.py", line 123, in run
infile_name = self.download_s3_file(s3_filename)
  File "target.py", line 47, in download_s3_file
s3.download_file(Bucket=os.environ.get('SP_BUCKET'), Key=s3_filename, Filename=local_filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 172, in download_file
extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 307, in download_file
future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 73, in result
return self._coordinator.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 233, in result
raise self._exception
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 255, in _main
self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3transfer/download.py", line 353, in _submit
**transfer_future.meta.call_args.extra_args
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 612, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found
```

Thanks y'all

[image]

Comment: Just a thought - try printing out `s3_file_full_path` to see if it is what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

`S3.Client.download_file` doesn't support a `Key` argument that is a regular expression. <sup>[1](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file)</sup>

`s3_file_full_path` evaluates to a object similar to the below one

```
re.compile(r'snowplow-enrich-output/enriched/archive/run=2019-02-24-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}/*.',
re.UNICODE)
```

No object in the snapshot of your bucket is so named.

The only way to go about this is to list the bucket objects and match their keys against the above regular expression object. <sup>[2](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2)</sup>

The above regular expression is similar to listing objects with Keys having their names prefix as `'snowplow-enrich-output/enriched/archive/run=2019-02-24-'`

```
list_object_kwargs = {
    'Bucket': os.environ.get('SP_BUCKET'),
    'Prefix': 'snowplow-enrich-output/enriched/archive/run=2019-02-24-'
}

def object_keys(contents):
    return [content['Key'] for content in contents]

objects = s3.list_objects_v2(**list_object_kwargs)
found_object_keys = object_keys(objects['Contents'])

while objects['IsTruncated']:
    objects = s3.list_objects_v2(
        ContinuationToken=objects['ContinuationToken'],
        **list_object_kwargs
    )
    found_object_keys.extend(object_keys(objects['Contents']))

try:
    for key in found_object_keys:
        s3.download_file(
            Bucket=os.environ.get('SP_BUCKET'), 
            Key=key)
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(
        "Could not retrieve %s because: %s" % (key, e))
    raise
```